# JQuery $('form').serialize() produces empty results

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3f6ouqw/2/

```
<form method="POST" id="sampleForm" action="/">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email"
               class="form-control"
               id="exampleInputEmail1"
               aria-describedby="emailHelp"
               placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp"
                 class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password"
               class="form-control"
               id="exampleInputPassword1"
               placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateControl">Date</label>
        <div class="input-group date"
               data-provide="datepicker">
          <input type="text"
                 class="form-control"
                 id="dateControl">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!-- Example of select picker -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectControl">Type</label>
        <select class="selectpicker"
               id="selectControl">
          <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit"
         class="btn btn-primary" id="sampleFormSubmitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        alert($("form").serialize());
        console.log(alert($("form").serialize()));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and I'm always getting empty str. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> add `name` in `input` and `select`

For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a **name** attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        alert($("form").serialize());
        console.log(alert($("form").serialize()));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="sampleForm" action="/">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input name="email" type="email"
               class="form-control"
               id="exampleInputEmail1"
               aria-describedby="emailHelp"
               placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp"
                 class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password"
               class="form-control"
               id="exampleInputPassword1"
               placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateControl">Date</label>
        <div class="input-group date"
               data-provide="datepicker">
          <input name="dateControl" type="text"
                 class="form-control"
                 id="dateControl">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!-- Example of select picker -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectControl">Type</label>
        <select name="selectpicker" class="selectpicker"
               id="selectControl">
          <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit"
         class="btn btn-primary" id="sampleFormSubmitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because none of your input elements, ie. the `input`, `select`, `textarea` etc., have `name` attributes.

These are required to make the HTML valid, and are also what the `serialize()` method uses as the keys to associate the values to.

Add `name` attributes on the HTML fields and your JS code will work fine.